# Tcl/Tk Referencing user-selected values in script

Tags: r, tcl, rstudio, tk-toolkit

A quick question regarding Tcl/Tk and R. Below I have a slice of code that corresponds with a Tk button that executes the `ToDo<-function(){...}`.

My presumption is that both `summary.myData()` and `ggplot()` commands will execute. With this said, my question is whether or not I have correctly coded each command to reference the correct selected variable (the tk widget controlling this is working just fine, thus not depicted).

Namely if the arguments for each command are valid.

```
summary.myData<-summarySE(myData, measurevar=paste(tx.choice1), groupvars=paste(tx.choice2),conf.interval=0.95,na.rm=TRUE,.drop=FALSE)
```

would be read by R as

```
summary.myData<-summarySE(myData, measurevar=Measure, groupvars=Group,conf.interval=0.95,na.rm=TRUE,.drop=FALSE)
```

and

```
ggplot(data=summary.myData,aes(x=paste(tx.choice2),y=paste(tx.choice1)))+
                      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=formula(paste(tx.choice1),"-ci"),ymax=formula(paste(tx.choice1),"+ci")), colour="black", width=.5, position=pd)+
                      geom_point(position=pd, size=3)+
                      labs(title=paste("Interval Plot of",tx.choice1,"By",tx.choice2))
```

will be read as

```
ggplot(data=summary.mydata, aes(x=Group, y=Measure))+
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Measure-ci, ymax=Measure+ci), colour="black", width=.5, position=pd)+
    geom_point(position=pd, size=3)+
    labs(title = "New plot title",x="X",y="y")
```

The slice for reference:

```
ToDo<-function(){
    tx.choice1<<-vars.name.num[as.integer(tkcurselection(tl1))+1]
    tx.choice2<<-vars.name.fac[as.integer(tkcurselection(tl2))+1]
    numb.select.num<<-length(tx.choice1)
    numb.select.fac<<-length(tx.choice2)

    windows()
    if (numb.select.num!=0){
      if (numb.select.fac==0){
        stop(tkmessageBox(message="Please select at least one categorical variable!", icon="error"))
      } 
      else if (numb.select.fac==1) {
        if(tclvalue(intervalplot_title)=="" & tclvalue(intervalplot_x)=="" & tclvalue(intervalplot_y)==""){
          summary.myData<-summarySE(myData, measurevar=paste(tx.choice1), groupvars=paste(tx.choice2),conf.interval=0.95,na.rm=TRUE,.drop=FALSE)
          ggplot(data=summary.myData,aes(x=paste(tx.choice2),y=paste(tx.choice1)))+
                      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=formula(paste(tx.choice1),"-ci"),ymax=formula(paste(tx.choice1),"+ci")), colour="black", width=.5, position=pd)+
                      geom_point(position=pd, size=3)+
                      labs(title=paste("Interval Plot of",tx.choice1,"By",tx.choice2))
        } else {
          summary.myData<-summarySE(myData, measurevar=paste(tx.choice1), groupvars=c(paste(tx.choice2)),conf.interval=0.95,na.rm=TRUE,.drop=FALSE)
          ggplot(data=summary.myData,aes(x=paste(tx.choice2),y=paste(tx.choice1)))+
                      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=paste(tx.choice1)-ci,ymax=paste(tx.choice1)+ci), colour="black", width=.5, position=pd)+
                      geom_point(position=pd, size=3)+
                      labs(title=tclvalue(intervalplot_title),x=tclvalue(intervalplot_x),y=tclvalue(intervalplot_y))
        }
        tkinsert(txt,"end",paste("\nIntervalplot of", tx.choice1,"By",tx.choice2[1],"\n\n"))
      }
}
```

Comment: After a little more testing, it is specifically `geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=formula(paste(tx.choice1),"-ci"),ymax=formula(paste(tx.choice1),"+ci")), colour="black", width=.5, position=pd)+` that is not correctly fetching the values from the dataset `summary.myData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, the correct usage would just be `paste(tx.choice1,"-ci")`. There is no need to add the `formula()` condition.